Does a visiting ranking officer on a Starfleet vessel assume command if the command staff of higher rank of the vessel are incapacitated?
In situations where the ranking command staff are incapacitated or otherwise unavailable, but a visitor was present who has higher rank than others on board, would that visitor automatically be expected to assume command? Or would the chain of command on the ship itself have to be respected?
For instance, in VOY: Equinox, was Janeway in command of any Equinox crew during the first rescue attempt? That is, could she have given orders, organized Equinox crew into search parties etc, presuming any were found in any condition to support? It is established in the episode that Janeway eventually has command authority due to having the tactically superior ship, but again I'm asking about the crisis situation, not, say, in a flotilla.
We see in TNG: The Pegasus that Pressman explicitly clarified that Picard would remain in command of the Enterprise but Pressman is in the command of the mission, so it stands to reason that visitors of higher rank than the commanding officer do take command if needed. I'm wondering about whether or not they automatically get command in the event of something incapacitating the command staff of equal rank even if they haven't taken command of anything during normal operations.

The fact that Pressman needs to explain the situation tells us that this is an abnormal situation. Picard shouldn't be the junior officer on his own ship, which is why Pressman makes it abundantly clear that he's not taking command, except where the mission is concerned.

And then there were the situations in TOS where in "The Galileo Seven", Commodore Ferris asserts his mission authority over Kirk, and in "A Taste of Armageddon", Ambassador Fox asserts his authority over Scotty... in Fox's case, a Federation official, essentially a civilian, with no Starfleet rank.

I'm sure there is a duplicate of this somewhere in the system.

@DJClayworth https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171579/can-a-lower-ranking-officer-captain-for-example-be-in-charge-of-a-ship-with-a/171590#171590 is similar, but not a duplicate.

@T.J.L. Not the one I'm thinking of, but good find.

If the practice in Starfleet is the same as historical and current military practice, which it appears to be the case, then chain of command would be followed.
From the Wikipedia article:

In general, military personnel give orders only to those directly
below them in the chain of command and receive orders only from those
directly above them. A service member who has difficulty executing a
duty or order and appeals for relief directly to an officer above his
immediate commander in the chain of command is likely to be
disciplined for not respecting the chain of command. Similarly, an
officer is usually expected to give orders only to his or her direct
subordinate(s), even if only to pass an order down to another service
member lower in the chain of command than said subordinate.
The concept of chain of command also implies that higher rank alone
does not entitle a higher-ranking service member to give commands to
anyone of lower rank. For example, an officer of unit "A" does not
directly command lower-ranking members of unit "B", and is generally
expected to approach an officer of unit "B" if he requires action by
members of that unit. The chain of command means that individual
members take orders from only one superior and only give orders to a
defined group of people immediately below them.
If an officer of unit "A" does give orders directly to a lower-ranked
member of unit "B", it would be considered highly unusual (i.e., a
faux pas, or extraordinary circumstances, such as a lack of time or
inability to confer with the officer in command of unit "B") as
officer "A" would be seen as subverting the authority of the officer
of unit "B". Depending on the situation or the standard procedure of
the military organization, the lower-ranked member being ordered may
choose to carry out the order anyway, or advise that it has to be
cleared with his or her own chain of command first, which in this
example would be with officer "B".

In fact, even in the case where the higher-ranked person (for example Pressman) is in charge of the lower-ranked person (for example, LaForge), it would normally be improper for orders to be given directly vice through the intermediary (Picard in this example).

Similarly, an officer is usually expected to give orders only to his
or her direct subordinate(s), even if only to pass an order down to
another service member lower in the chain of command than said
subordinate.

The case of Janeway in the initial rescue of the Equinox would probably fall in the category of "extraordinary circumstances."
As far as I can tell, all current militaries (and past militaries back to the beginning of the modern age) have basically the same policies on chain of command.

Starfleet procedures, according to Roddenberry, was based on the British Naval tradition rather than the US military. He was also keen that it be a paramilitary organisation rather than an outright military, hence why Picard is flying around in a glorified city and why there are civilians on the Enterprise.

I believe (and will confirm if possible) that chain of command principles are basically the same for all modern militaries

In a word, no. Had the captain of the Equinox been injured or incapacitated, his First Officer would have assumed command of the ship and hence been the same rank as Captain Janeway, albeit on a pro-tem basis.
That all being said, Starfleet is nothing but pragmatic. I think it's reasonably likely that if the crew had been reduced to reporting to the Second Officer or below, that Janeway would be expected to take control of the situation as senior officer (in the same way that Picard took control of the Home Defence Fleet in First Contact) and start giving out orders and put one of her senior officers, presumably Chakotay or Tuvok, in charge of the Equinox.



